# jquery tabs dynamic parameter is received as null

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a table on top of my page and 3 tabs below it. When you click on a row in the table it gets an ID from that row, stores it in a global variable and then refreshes the first tab. I need to pass that ID as a parameter to the controller behind the scenes for that tab. The action method is getting called but the parameter is always null. I have a function that gets the ID and inside this function I alert it out and it does have the right ID, but for some reason the action behind the scenes always has the parameter as null.

```
// action that is getting called but the parameter 'id' is always null
public PartialViewResult GetPriceDetail(string id)
{
    return PartialView("_Price");
}


<script>
    // global var to store the last id
    var ID = -1;

    // when this does the alert the ID is correct. it is the one I clicked on the table
    function GetID(){
        alert("Inside GetID() = " + ID);
        return ID;
    }

    $("#tabs").tabs({
        load: function(event, ui){

        },
        beforeLoad: function(e, ui){
            ui.ajaxSettings.id= GetID();
        }
    });

    // called when you click the first cell of each column since they are links with ID's
    function ShowParams(id) {
        ID = id;

        // highlight the row in the table that has this value to show it's selected
        $("#simHeaderTable").find("tr").each(function () {
            var tdID = $(this).find("td:first-child").text();

            if (tdID == ID){
                $(this).children("td").css("background-color", "#FFFF66");
            }
            else
                $(this).children("td").removeAttr("style");
        });

        // reload the Price tab now that we have set the ID
        $("#tabs").tabs("load", 0);
    }
</script>
```

Here is what the li looks like. Not sure if this has anything to do with it.

```
<li><a href='@Url.Action("GetPriceDetail", "Home")'>Price</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the data type from string to int in the GetPriceDetail method?

Comment: Yeah. If I do that then the action doesn't get called at all and in the javascript console it gives an error saying it can't find the action.

Comment: What about passing the id as a parameter inside Url.Action. Like this...@Url.Action("GetPriceDetail", "Home", new { id = <reference your client side id value here> })

Comment: The ID is clicked on the same page as the tabs and the tabs are reused and show different data based on the ID clicked. Isn't that built when the page comes back initially? I want this all done via ajax so no page reloads.

Answer (score 0):

Hacked around this issue by building the url to have the parameter to it:

```
beforeLoad: function(e, ui){
    ui.ajaxSettings.url += ( /\?/.test( ui.ajaxSettings.url ) ? "&" : "?" ) + 'id=' + ID;
}
```

Not thrilled but it works for my case.